# Filtering a list using except on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a method which will ultimately give me a collection of records which no longer have a corresponding record within a different collection to which I am referencing.

The structure is something similar to:

```
public class A
{
    int id {get; set;}
    int recId {get; set;}
    string category {get; set;}
}


public class B
{
    int recId {get; set;}
    string category {get; set;}
}
```

So far I have the following bit of LINQ to give me my collection of missing records but this only giving me any `recId` that is missing:

```
var noLongerHaveRecordInCollectionB =
CollectionA.Select(x => x.recId).Except(CollectionB.Select(x => x.recId));
```

I need a `List<A>` of every record which:

1.) No longer has a `recId` held in the `CollectionB`.

OR

2.) No longer has a record which has a matching `recId` and `category` in `CollectionB`

For **example** it is possible that within `CollectionA` there are 2 records with the same `recId` but different `category`.

If `CollectionB` now only contains 1 record for that `recId` I would want to remove the record in `CollectionA` which does not have the corresponding category.

So the ultimate question is how can I populate `noLongerHaveRecordInCollectionB` with all `<T>` A's that have been checked against `CollectionB` and not just the `recId` as it currently does, I want the whole object.

**edit: input/result**

**CollectionA**

1,2254,Category A

2,2236,Category A

3,2415,Category B

4,1275,Category B   <--- same person as below, diff category

5,1275,Category C   <--- same person as above, diff category

**CollectionB**

2254,Category A

2415,Category B

1275,Category C

**Expected Result**

I would expect (from CollectionA) the following id's to be highlighted in my list for deletion: 2, 4

Comment: `CollectionA.Where(x=>CollectionB.Select(y=>y.recId).Contains(x.recId))` will give you the records, not just the ids.

Comment: This will not consider the category though?

Comment: You can always use set methods like `Enumerable.Except` and use another set method `Join` to  get the complete data.

Comment: Can you provide a clear sample of input data and a result you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achive what you want by using `Where` clause with `||` condition. No need to go for the complex solution.

```
 var result = collectionA.Where(a => collectionB.Any(b => a.recId == b.recId && a.Category != b.Category)
              || !collectionB.Any(b => b.recId == a.recId));
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can implement [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for your class and compare the objects based on the fields you are interested in.For example implement the Equals method like this:

```
public bool Equals(A a, B b)
{
    return a.recId  == b.recId && a.category == b.category ;
}
```

Then just call Except method and pass your `comparer`:

```
var resultList = CollectionA .Except(CollectionB, new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Or if you implement it on your class, instead of a separate `comparer` you can just call `Except`:

```
var resultList = CollectionA .Except(CollectionB);
```

Be aware that you need also implement `GetHashCode` method.

**UPDATE**

If you want to go with the `IEqualityComparer<T>`you can create a new List from the second list:

```
  var secondListA = CollectionB.Select(x=> new A(){Category=x.Category, recId=x.recId});
```

And then create your `Comparer`:

```
sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;
        else if (y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return x.recId== y.recId&& x.Category == y.Category;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return obj.recId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use `Except()` overload which produces the set difference of two sequences by using the specified `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare values.:

```
    var result = CollectionA.Except(secondListA, new MyComparer ());
```

But I think you should go with the simple `Where` filter as creating new List of `A` type can cause lot of performance overhade.

Comment: How do you implement the GetHashCode method?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use set methods like `Enumerable.Except` and use another set method `Join` to  get the complete data.

> I need a `List<A>` of every record which:
>   1.) No longer has a `recId` held in the `CollectionB`.

```
var onlyInA = CollectionA.Select(x => x.recId).Except(CollectionB.Select(x => x.recId));
var dataOnlyInA = from a in CollectionA
                  join recId in onlyInA 
                  on a.onlyInA equals recId 
                  select a;
List<A> result =  dataOnlyInA.ToList();
```

> 2.) No longer has a record which has a matching `recId` and `category` in `CollectionB`

Maybe:

```
var canBeRemovedFromA = CollectionA
    .Where(a => CollectionB.Any(b => a.recID == b.recId && a.category!= b.category));
```

this doesn't check if there is at least one matching category. It's not clear if that's a must.